# How to send back TCP packets using iptables

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, tcp

I am trying to demonstrate TCP communication with a Ubuntu 18.04 box (which mocks a QNX setup) that does not have a listener installed. Consider that due to some license issues it might not be possible to load and run a listener program any time soon either. Is it possible to use iptables to accept connection from a client, receive incoming packets and send them back to the client?

If yes, what are the commands?
I want to use netcat to demonstrate sending and receiving of messages.

I have tried following command from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1671128/returning-tcp-udp-packets-to-sender) link.

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.ens4.route_localnet=1
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ens4 -o ens4 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

I have also tried below commands from another StackOverflow question.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <IP>:80
sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <IP>:80
```

But netcat exits immediately. Not sure whether it even attempted connection.

```
netcat <IP> 80
```

Other ideas than iptables are also welcome.

Comment: well, if you send an actual TCP segment you have received back exactly as is, it will not be accepted as part of the connection due to the syn values not matching up. the data would need to be repackaged into a new segment that is valid for the connection.

Comment: you can install a listener

Comment: @user253751 I don't have access to do so, that is the challenge

Comment: @FrankThomas is that possible with iptables? If so can you please add the steps as an answer

Comment: @kingvittu is this like a hacking challenge where the goal is to make something happen with only limited access? or why can't you do it?

Comment: @user253751 target OS is a QNX image for which we don't have access to install commands like netcat, run Python code or build/run any TCP server. Hence came with this idea is to tweak firewall rules to demonstrate TCP communication. I have updated the question. As a proof of concept I am trying to use iptables to show TCP between 2 Linux machines.

Answer (score 0):

For simple demos, it might be easier to also forward traffic using `ncat`, like in the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293304/using-netcat-for-port-forwarding). Basically just use ncat as your listener, then launch another ncat to resend any data back to your client. (Make sure your client is also listening for this data on whatever port you choose)

```
ncat -l 10.0.0.1 80 --sh-exec "ncat 10.0.0.2 80"
```

This is good enough to see your own sent traffic, but only works in one direction. If you need to see something with back-and-forth like web traffic, then you probably want something more advanced like the iptables routing you tried.

The `dnat` in your rules stands for **d**estination network address translation, and they only remap the destination IP for packets. Since your planned source and destination are the same IP, you also need to set up `snat` rules to remap the source IP address:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp --dst $HOST_IP   --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination $CLIENT_IP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dst $CLIENT_IP --dport 8000 -j SNAT --to-source $HOST_IP
```

I found a couple good writeups on this:

- [Linux Packet Filtering and iptables DNAT guide](https://www.linuxtopia.org/Linux_Firewall_iptables/x4013.html)
- [Some examples of SNAT, DNAT with iptables with comments](https://gist.github.com/tomasinouk/eec152019311b09905cd)
- [Enabling IP forwarding on the interfaces](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/linux-router-and-ip-forwarding/#enable-ip-forwarding), also contains iptables steps for configuring as a gateway

---

Example test case on client:

```sh
# listen on port 8000 in background
nc -l 8000 > nc.out &
# verify netcat is listening on client
netstat -ln | grep 8000

# send some data to server via netcat, and you should see job finish if server forwarded successfully
echo hello world | nc 10.0.0.1 8000
[1]+  Done                    nc -l 8000 > nc.out

# and you should see your data captured
cat nc.out
hello world
```

depending on your distro, you might not be able to listen on protected ports like 80 (selinux may block for example). Make sure you've enabled ip forwarding, as it's usually off by default:

```
# check current status
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
```

Comment: Actually the actual machine would be a QNX machine.  I have updated the question. So netcat or any other regular methods is not possible as of now. We don't have license to compile any program yet and also Python is not available which limits us to put any listener. The firewall commands I will try and let you know soon.

Comment: The iptables command you gave didn't work for me

Comment: @kingvittu what did you try that didn't work? I've added an example to test out

Comment: In the above example, does the server run also on the client machine, and the host machine is made as via path? If so, how do I check if the packets were indeed received in the host?

Comment: @kingvittu all of the netcat stuff is run on the client. Only the iptables and ip_forward commands would be done on the host/server. If you want to see whether the server is receiving packets, you can use `iptables -vL` to list the stats on each rule (to see if the redirect rules are getting used). Otherwise it's probably a job for `tcpdump`

Comment: `sudo tcpdump -i any port 8000 -n` is not showing any packets on server. On client the `10.0.0.1` IP doesn't connect. When I change it to `$CLIENT_IP` value, `hello world` is written but tcpdump doesn't show anything. Perhaps some iptables routing should be done on client side as well?